# Generic BufReader?

Tags: rust

I want to pass a `BufReader` instance to a separate function:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("test.txt")?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(f);
    read(reader);
}

fn read(reader: &mut BufReader) {
    // todo
}
```

but get an error about a missing generic argument for `BufReader<R>`. What generic parameter to use - `String`, because that's what I want to read? Sorry for my ignorance - I only know generics from Java.

Comment: The value of `R` depends on the argument passed to [`BufReader::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.new). In this case, you passed a `File`, so `reader` (in `main`) is a `BufReader<File>`. That said, I would make the `read` function generic, as suggested in [Netwave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70672846/234590).

Comment: I would assume you probably want the `BufRead` trait instead of the `BufReader` wrapper anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the type generic, constrained to `Read` (so your method would work for any type buffered reader that implements `Read` itself):

```rust
fn read<R: Read>(reader: &mut BufReader<R>) {
    // todo
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0cbc62c67fbd469c20fe00483c0d5966)

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html):

> The BufReader struct adds buffering to any reader.
>
> It can be excessively inefficient to work directly with a Read
> instance. For example, every call to read on TcpStream results in a
> system call. **A BufReader performs large, infrequent reads on the
> underlying Read and maintains an in-memory buffer of the results.**

Also, check on [rust generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html)

Comment: Since you're using generics anyway, an even more generic (pun intended) option is `fn read<R: BufRead>(reader: R)`. That will accept any type that implements the `BufRead` trait, including but not limited to `BufReader`. (For example, `io::Cursor<Vec<u8>>` implements `Read` and `BufRead`, which would enable you to send `Vec<u8>` to `read()` without wrapping it in an unnecessary `BufReader`.)